# What is the best approach to keep locally data on a tablet windows application?

Tags: c#, .net, local-storage, tablet

I have to write a windows forms application that will run on tablet PCs with Windows 7.

This application will handle a stock taking on a warehouse with no connectivity to our central ERP. the user will scan the barcode label and the application will have to keep the data locally.

At the end of the operation the user will be able via LAN to upload the data on our ERPs table.

thus my question is what is the best way to keep the scanned data locally?

Option 1: Simple Text files (custom txt or XML)

Option 2: SQL Server compact edition?

Option 3 : ????

I don't quite like the idea of text files as i have to open and close them every 30-40 seconds that the user will scan labels. Is SQL Compact the best way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only storing something simple like a SKU and quantity, and not modifying/replacing values, a text file will be extremely fast and simple. You can open a text file for append and just add lines on the end, then close the file. You could also use XML and serialization, but if there are just a couple of values then a plain text file format would be simplest and serialization will add development labor and has more potential for performance issues, deserializing, updating, then reserializing the object back to disk over and over.

A DB might be necessary if you want to have relational data, or if somehow multiple users/devices could access simultaneously, or if you need rowset operations for data modification. If you use any db it will also access the file system every time there is a new row, same as using a file.

Comment: I would prefer text file, but if i keep the file open for append all the time i risk file corruption in case if something happens and i will loose all the data up to that monent, so i will have to open and close the text file in every scan to be sure. yes?

Comment: You don't really risk much corruption, you might end up with a locked file if the process dies, so you might as well open the file every time you write to it and then immediately close it. With File.AppendAllLines() you could do the entire file writing in one line and not worry about locking/corruption etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Just make sure you store a device ID in each table where they can perform updates.  Then when they sync back to the shared SQL Server with merge replication, none of the entries will conflict.

Comment: You mean to include in my results table fields like machine, user,date time etc, in order not to have problem during my sync?

Comment: each device should have a device ID you can query and it will return that you can use to uniquely identify it.  If something else is unique for each device, you can use that instead.